# How can I tell a regular language?

Tags: automation, regular-language, dfa, nfa, pumping-lemma

As we know, using pumping lemma, we can easily prove the language **L = {WW|W ∈ {a,b}*}** is not a regular language.

However, The language, L1 = {W1W2| |W1| = |W2|} is a regular language. Because we can get the DFA like below,
[image]

My question is, **L = {WW|W ∈ {a,b}*}** also has the even length of strings (|w|=|w|, definitely), L still can have some dfa like above. How come it not a regular language?

Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion, this question belongs to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Personally, I'd say http://cs.stackexchange.com, as this doesn't seem like something you'd write a Ph.D. about? Maybe I'm just too snobby, in that regard. =)

Comment: @dema80, Yeap, wrong place to put this thread. Sorry.:-)

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting languages `ww` and language of `DFA` that is L1:

**[Question]**:

- `L ={ ww| w = w}` is a Regular Language`(RL)`. Because we can get the `DFA` like below is possible.

  ```
  DFA:  L1 ={ w1w2| |w1| = |w2|, where w1 , w2 ∈ {a, b}* } 

  --►((even))------a,b---------►(odd)  
        ▲                         |  
        |--------a,b--------------|
  ```

**[DOUBT]**

> What is **L** ={ ww | where w ∈ {a, b}* }  is ?

L is even length string consist of `a` and `b` that is has some prefix sub string equal to suffix sub string. some example of `L` are `{ aa, bb, abab, aaaa, bbbb, abaaba, abbabb, .....}`

> Whats language of **DFA**  or L1 ={ w1w2| |w1| = |w2|, where w1 , w2 ∈ {a, b}* } ?

All even length strings consist of `a` and `b` say `L1` for  example `{ab, ba, aabb, baab, ab, aa, bb, ababa, baba, abbba, ...}`

*Note:*  all even length strings consist of `a` and `b` are not in `L` for  example `{ab, ba, aabb, baab, ab}` but this string in `DFA`'s language = L1.

so, `L(DFA)=L1 != L`

**[DOUBT-1]**

> Relation between `L` and `L(DFA)=L1` ?

As I wrote in *note*, `L ⊆ L(DFA)` so every string that belongs to `L` also element of language of DFA and accepted you `DFA`.  (*this is you confusion*)

Also, language `L ={ ww| |w| = |w| }`  is not Regular Language.And we can't draw `DFA` for this language. BOTH LANGUAGES ARE NOT SAME! `(L  != L1)`

`L` is much restricted then `L(DFA)`

`L`= `{ WW|W }` is not regular can be proof using pumping lemma.

<sub>`L` also not even context free language, but context sensitive language</sub>

Comment: Hi, Grijesh, I really appreciate you for putting so much effort on this thread!! :-)  As you mention, "Note: all even length strings consist of a and b are not in L1 for example {ab, ba, aabb, baab, ab} but this string in DFA's language."  I don't know why L1 can not contain these strings, since W1 maybe not equal to W2, ONLY the length of W1 and W2 are the same. That means, if W1=a, W2=b, then the string is ab ∈ L1. Form "even" state ---> a ---> "odd" state ---> b ---> "even" state. Accept.

Answer (score 0):

I post this thead in cs.stackexchange, and Ran provide me the answer. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/how-come-ww-isnt-regular-when-uv-u-v-is

The key difference between the two language is the first one doesn't need to remember its contents just to calculate the length is enough, while the second language need to analyse whether w and w are identical.

Thanks @Ran, @Grijesh and @dema80 :-)